# Github Pages and React App not working regardless of methods

Tags: javascript, reactjs, git, github, redux

I've been trying to add my React App project to Github Pages for a week. After all the prep work and everything that need to be done, I finally got it to show up, well kinda. It actually doesn't show anything, nor does it give me errors. Which leads me to believe that my script

```
<script src="../dist/bundle.js"></script>
```

is the culprit. However, the problem is I've never once used bundle.js. I wanted to learn how to use React without using create-react-app, and in doing so I seem to have gotten to far along in the game I'm not even sure how this is supposed to work.

Here is the Github Pages in it's current form

https://kevin6767.github.io/redux-api-opendota2/

EDIT: It now seems to be showing a 404. I'm not even sure why this is not working at this point. I've tried to many different methods.

Comment: First, I think it shouldn't say 404 if `index.html` file is there.

Comment: @ajeetshah in the docs folder https://github.com/kevin6767/redux-api-opendota2

Comment: [This](https://pages.github.com/) says you have to create a github repository with name: `username.github.io` where `username` should be your GitHub username. You should correct your repository name first.

Answer (score 7):

I am not sure how you uploaded your React application to GitHub Pages, but, here, I will be mentioning the correct way to do it:

**Step 1**: Install `gh-pages` via the terminal, making sure you are in the correct file directory.

`$ npm install gh-pages --save -dev` (We are saving it as a dev dependency)

**Step 2**: Go to your `package.json` and add

`"homepage": "<YOUR_GITHUB_USERNAME>.github.io/<REPO_NAME>,"` above the `"name"`

**Step 3**: In the `"scripts"` section of `package.json`, add

`"predeploy": "npm run build", "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",`

**Step 4**: Assuming that you have already committed and pushed your code to your Git Repo, now, in the terminal, use the command `npm run deploy` to see the changes in your GitHub Pages.

Also, make sure that in your source code, you have set the same route for the `homepage` as in the `package.json`.